# UIWebView elementFromPoint js method return 'wrong' element

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

`UIWebView` has a 'fake header' on its private `UIBrowserView` which is `webView.scrollView.subviews[0]`.When I use js `elementFromPoint` js method it may return "wrong" element.But when I remove the 'fake header',the return is absolutely right.
iOS 7 Later

Answer (score 0):

By judge the conetentOffset,I can calculate the corrent point which should be send to the elementFromPoint js method.